# ggplot set binlocation for stats_binhex

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to generate two "overlayed" graph using stats_binhex

The idea is that the first binhex graph shows the potential location of the data. This is to illustrate the "domain" of the data. The second binhex is then showing the selected data.
However, if I filter out data from the y-range, the overlay plot is strangely distorted

```
data <- mtcars
subdata<-data[which(data["disp"]>200),]
ggplot(subdata)+
   stat_binhex(data=data,
               fill="white",
               aes(x=mpg,y=disp))+
   stat_binhex(aes(x=mpg,y=disp))
```

I have the feeling that I have to set the bin location. But all attempts to do so haven't solve the issue.

Illustration of the issue: [image: https://pl.vc/4kinz]

**UPDATE**
With the hint provided below by MLavoie, can be made a little bit nicer, however, the center region is still distorted and performance is negatively impacted

```
plot.fun <- function(data,selector){
  print(max(data[-selector,"Sepal.Length"]))
  ggplot(data[selector,])+
     stat_binhex(data=data[-selector,],fill="white",aes(y=Sepal.Length,x=Sepal.Width))+
     stat_binhex(aes(y=Sepal.Length,x=Sepal.Width))
 }


   plot.fun(iris,which(data["Sepal.Length"]>6))
```

[image: Version 2 on iris]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the christmas holiday to dissect the bin_hex code and post the solution here, if someone has the same problem in future.

The problem is due to the fact that the location of the bins is calculated without incooperating the geom objects. Instead it is calculate on the data `x` for the plot at hand.

```
  xbnds <- c(
    plyr::round_any(min(x), binwidth[1], floor) - 1e-6,
    plyr::round_any(max(x), binwidth[1], ceiling) + 1e-6
  )
  xbins <- diff(xbnds) / binwidth[1]

  ybnds <- c(
    plyr::round_any(min(y), binwidth[2], floor) - 1e-6,
    plyr::round_any(max(y), binwidth[2], ceiling) + 1e-6
  )
  ybins <- diff(ybnds) / binwidth[2]
```

One solution would be to set the location of the split always at one of the `n` location `min(y)+n*(max(y)+min(y))/binwidth`.

However, I decided to calc my own layer based on the bin hex code, where I calculate the limit as

```
xbnds <- scales$x$dimension()
ybnds <- scales$y$dimension()
```

this appears to be the cleaner solution and yields the following result
[image]

The complete code is:

```
#' @export
#' @rdname geom_hex
#' @inheritParams stat_bin_2d
stat_bin_hex2 <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "hex",
                         position = "identity", bins = 30, binwidth = NULL,
                         na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
                         ...) {
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = StatBinhex2,
    geom = geom,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      bins = bins,
      binwidth = binwidth,
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}

#' @export
#' @rdname geom_hex
#' @usage NULL
stat_binhex <- stat_bin_hex

#' @rdname ggplot2-ggproto
#' @format NULL
#' @usage NULL
#' @export
StatBinhex2 <- ggproto("StatBinhex", Stat,
                      default_aes = aes(fill = ..count..),

                      required_aes = c("x", "y"),

                      compute_group = function(data, scales, binwidth = NULL, bins = 30,
                                               na.rm = FALSE) {

                        if (is.null(binwidth)) {
                          binwidth <- c(
                            diff(scales$x$dimension()) / bins,
                            diff(scales$y$dimension()) / bins
                          )
                        }

                        hexBin2(data$x, data$y, binwidth,scales)
                      }
)

# Bin 2d plane into hexagons
# Wrapper around \code{\link[hexbin]{hcell2xy}} that returns a data frame
#
# @param x positions
# @param y positions
# @param numeric vector of length 2 giving binwidth in x and y directions
# @keyword internal
hexBin2 <- function(x, y, binwidth,scales) {
  # Convert binwidths into bounds + nbins
  View(scales$y$dimension())

#the changed calculation of x/ybnds is the crucial differenc  
  xbnds <- scales$x$dimension()
  ybnds <- scales$y$dimension()
  #xbnds <- c(
  #  plyr::round_any(min(x), binwidth[1], floor) - 1e-6,
  #  plyr::round_any(max(x), binwidth[1], ceiling) + 1e-6
  #)
  xbins <- diff(xbnds) / binwidth[1]

  #ybnds <- c(
  #  plyr::round_any(min(y), binwidth[2], floor) - 1e-6,
  #  plyr::round_any(max(y), binwidth[2], ceiling) + 1e-6
  #)
  ybins <- diff(ybnds) / binwidth[2]

  # Call hexbin
  hb <- hexbin::hexbin(
    x, xbnds = xbnds, xbins = xbins,
    y, ybnds = ybnds, shape = ybins / xbins
  )

  # Convert to data frame
  data.frame(
    hexbin::hcell2xy(hb),
    count = hb@count,
    density = hb@count / sum(hb@count, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
}


plot.fun <- function(data,selector){

         ggplot(data[selector,])+
             stat_bin_hex2(data=data,fill="white",aes(y=Sepal.Length,x=Sepal.Width))+
             stat_bin_hex2(aes(y=Sepal.Length,x=Sepal.Width))+
             scale_x_continuous(limit=c(min(iris$Sepal.Width),max(iris$Sepal.Width)))+
            scale_y_continuous(limit=c(min(iris$Sepal.Length),max(iris$Sepal.Length)))
}


plot.fun(iris,which(iris["Sepal.Length"]>5))
```

Answer (score 1):

is it what you want?

```
data <- mtcars
subdata<-data[which(data["disp"]>200),]; subdata2<-data[which(data["disp"]<200),]
ggplot(subdata)+
   stat_binhex(data=subdata2,
               fill="white",
               aes(x=mpg,y=disp))+
   stat_binhex(aes(x=mpg,y=disp))
```

[image]

Comment: Ok it seems to work on the mtcars, I need to check this tomorrow on my real world data.
Nevertheless the solution is a bit surprising and also unsatisfying. Do you have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: no idea, it's really weird..it took me a while before coming up with this solution..maybe somebody else will come up with a better solution and explanation :-)

Comment: Sadly It doesnt work either. However it looks much better. When I filter iris on Sepal.Length>6 one can see that the points are not aligned in the center region. I guess it is really about the location/center of the bins

    plot.fun <- function(data,selector){
      print(max(data[-selector,"Sepal.Length"]))
      ggplot(data[selector,])+
         stat_binhex(data=data[-selector,],fill="white",aes(y=Sepal.Length,x=Sepal.Width))+
        stat_binhex(aes(y=Sepal.Length,x=Sepal.Width))
        }

    plot.fun(iris,which(data["Sepal.Length"]>6))